# General solution for $\sin \theta$ = $0.82 \theta$

Tags: analytic-geometry

I was looking for values of $\theta$ which satisfy the above condition.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you think there is an easy solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are two, symmetric about $0$, approximately $\pm 1.069412588$.  No closed form, but you can use Newton's method.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. Can you give me a reference for newton's method that I can read up?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) or [these course notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~keshet/M102/M102CourseNotes/M102chap5.pdf)